# Losing reputation for downvoting a question/answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

This may be a silly question, but I've noticed the following in my reputation trend:

> -1    54 mins ago     downvoted   [Show wishlist only for logged in users](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6484/show-wishlist-only-for-logged-in-users/17862#17862)
>
> -1    1 hour ago  downvoted   [Add to wishlist without redirect to wishlist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/add-to-wishlist-without-redirect-to-wishlist/17861#17861)

I don't quite understand why I am losing reputation for downvoting a post which I think is deserving of being downvoted.

Could anybody explain the reasoning behind this? Would appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... these are the rules. [Read this to see how reputation works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Also [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) explains a bit why you get -1 rep when you downvote.

> -2 to post owner
>   -1 to you
>
> This is done to make sure downvotes are cast only when you feel
>   strongly that something is incorrect / wrong / dangerous / of low
>   quality.

And here is [an other explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62137/224252):

> Downvotes are important (very important!) but they are also
>   potentially divisive, so they are just slightly discourage with a
>   minor cost.
>
> The idea is that you will think twice about them and only apply them
>   where they really belong.
>
> 'Course, once you have oodles of rep the one point cost doesn't mean
>   much and you can feel free to cast them whenever it seem like a good
>   idea...

I guess these are the rules and we have to play by them.

And just to make it clear...you get -1 rep only when you downvote an answer. Question downvotes are free of charge.

Comment: Ahhh understood. Thanks Marius, -1 to me for skimming through the rules.